# Using .one() with .live() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was using the `live()` function:

```
$('a.remove_item').live('click',function(e) {});
```

I needed to change this to `one()` to prevent multiple clicks, however when I inject one of these elements after the page has loaded the `one()` listener does not fire.

How can I get `one()` to behave like `live()`?

Comment: do you want live click should work only once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a.remove_item').live('click',function(e) {
  if($(e.target).data('oneclicked')!='yes')
  {
    //Your code
  }
  $(e.target).data('oneclicked','yes');
});
```

This executes your code, but it also sets a flag 'oneclicked' as yes, so that it will not activate again. Basically just sets a setting to stop it from activating once it's been clicked once.

Comment: Good solution. I think it's better than JapanPro's because using the data function is more discrete than adding a class.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to actually remove the event without effecting other `$('a.remove_item')`'s

Answer (score 15):

Here's a plugin version for running a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler once, created purely out of boredom:

```
$.fn.liveAndLetDie = function(event, callback) {
    var sel = this.selector;
    function unbind() { $(sel).die(event, callback).die(event, unbind); }
    return this.live(event, callback).live(event, unbind);
};
```

It works just like [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) would (unless you need the event data argument, in which case you'd need to add the overload).  Just use it the same way:

```
$('a.remove_item').liveAndLetDie('click', function(e) { /* do stuff */ });
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5PhHk/1/).

Comment: I must note, there is a difference between this answer and the one marked as correct. With this answer, if you are applying it to a group of elements (i.e. `$('.class')`), it will only run once on any of the elements in the selector (i.e. if the first element was clicked, the second can't be clicked) while in the first answer, each element can only be clicked once (i.e. you can click the first element once, then the second element once, etc.). So in my case, I found the answer marked as correct more beneficial as compared to this one. Not suggesting any edits, just pointing out a difference.

Answer (score 11):

Just use [jQuery's `.die()` method](http://api.jquery.com/die/) in the handler:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Agzar/

```
$('a.remove_item').live('click',function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
   $('a.remove_item').die('click'); // This removes the .live() functionality
});​
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or if you only wanted to disable the event on a per-element basis, you could just change the class name since `live()` is selector-based.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Agzar/1/

```
$('a.remove_item').live('click',function(e) {
    alert('i was clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('remove_item remove_item_clicked');
});​
```

This changed the class from `remove_item` to `remove_item_clicked` which could have the same styling. Now `live()` will not fire after the first click.

Comment: I used this today. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('a.remove_item').live('click', function(e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked'))
    {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      alert("dd"); // this is clicked once, do something here
    }
});​
```

Comment: this would work similar to the data function, however like Kranu said this is less discrete. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this worked for me on a similar case:

```
$('a.remove_item').live('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Your code here
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it on $.ajax function, so, on the final, in my case fail, I use ,500 in order to delay it and stop to resend many times.

`}).fail(function(response, status){
    alert("FAILED: "+JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
},500);`

I hope it helps you!