# How to save event handlers, when we set new html for element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have simple html markup:

```
<div id="cont">Some text here
  <div class="wrap" style="border: 1px solid black;display: inline;"> block element here
  </div> and another text</div>
```

And jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
  $(".wrap").click(function(){
      $("#cont").html($("#cont").html().replace(/text/g, "letter"));
    alert("Click!");
  });
  $("#d1").click(function(){
    alert("#d1 clicked!");
  });
});
```

I expect that click event will be fire any time you clicked by the `#d1` div, but when we clicked by .wrap it neve fire again. I understand why it has such behavior, but how to solve it?
In my code I can't set click event for `#d1` after `$("#cont").html($("#cont").html().replace(/text/g, "letter"))` because I don't now at execution time if event was set.
You can try example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aqono4/2/edit)

Thanks for replies, [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is a very useful function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aqono4/4/edit

If you are unsure of the state of your elements you can always use `live` to bind your events:

```
$(function(){
    $(".wrap").live('click', function(){
        $("#cont").html($("#cont").html().replace(/text/g, "letter"));
        alert("Click!");
    });
    $("#d1").live('click', function(){
        alert("#d1 clicked!");
    });
});
```

Events bound with the [live method](http://api.jquery.com/live/), will still apply to instances found **after** the code is initially called.

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aqono4/4/edit

Comment: Is it possible to combine .live() and .one() event setters? I want to set event handler using .live(), but it must fire only once.

Comment: @Kai Not sure but you could put `$(this).die('click')` at the end of the handler function.

Comment: I find nice solution from @Nick Craver here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796207/using-one-with-live-jquery

Comment: **As of jQuery 1.7 `live` has been deprecated and removed in 1.9.**

Answer (score 1):

You should bind using the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

```
$(function(){  
   $(".wrap").live("click", function() {
   // ....
```

Answer (score 1):

As GvS said, bind the event. When you dont need it, you can unbind.