# Using .one() with .get()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**QUESTION:** What is the proper way to use .get() in conjunction with .one() (or .live()) so that an external php file is appended only once?

MOST RECENT EDIT:
**solution**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tree li a').one("click", function() {
    var currentAnchor = $('.tree li a').attr('href');
    if(!currentAnchor){
        var query = "page=1";
    }
    else
    {
    var splits = currentAnchor.substring(1).split('&');
    //Get the section
    var page = splits[0];
    delete splits[0];
    var query = "page=" + page;
    alert ("page=" + page);
    }
    //Send the petition
    $("#loading").show();
    $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
        $("#content").append(data);
        $("#loading").hide();
    });       
    return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

More Specifically:

I'm using Javascript and PHP to load some external PHP pages as sections in my main template.

I'm using a switch and append() so the included files keep appending. I need every file to be able to be appended ONLY ONCE. Here is the scenario as I'd like it to happen

1) downloads link is clicked

2) downloads.php appears

3) errors link  is clicked

4) errors.php appears below downloads.php

5) downloads link is clicked again

6) page just scrolls up to top of downloads.php

I need the same functionality as the example on the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/one/) of .one() where every div can be clicked only once.

I also looked at [Using .one() with .live() jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796207/using-one-with-live-jquery) and I especially liked the approach used in the accepted answer.

Iried using boolean flag as suggested below but all it did was limit my consecutive clicks on the same link to one. So if I click one `link 1` multiple times it'll show page 1.php only once but if I click on link 1, then link 2, then link 1 again it will display page 1.php, then append page 2.php and append another page 1.php.

I'm starting to think that the setInterval is wrong and I may use .one() for the whole `checkAnchor()` function and bind it to the `<a>` tags. I tried this but it's not working either :(((

**core.js** - using .one()

```
var currentAnchor = null;
//$(document).ready(checkAnchor);
//Function which chek if there are anchor changes, if there are, sends the ajax petition checkAnchor
$("a").one("click", function (){
//Check if it has changes
if(currentAnchor != document.location.hash){
    currentAnchor = document.location.hash;
    //if there is not anchor, the loads the default section
    if(!currentAnchor){
        query = "page=1";
    }
    else
    {
        //Creates the  string callback. This converts the url URL/#main&id=2 in URL/?section=main&id=2
        var splits = currentAnchor.substring(1).split('&');
        //Get the section
        var page = splits[0];
        delete splits[0];
        var query = "page=" + page;

    }
    alert ("hello");
    //Send the petition
    $("#loading").show();

    $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
        $("#content").append(data);
        $("#loading").hide();
        });


}
});
```

The other thing I liked as an approach is adding the names of the pages to an array and then checking that array to make sure the page wasn't displayed yet. I managed to fill up an array with the page names using .push() but I hit a dead end when looking up for a value in it. If you have an idea how that's supposed to look like that'd be very helpful as well.

**core.js**

```
///On load page
var contentLoaded;
$().ready(function(){
contentLoaded = false;
setInterval("checkAnchor()", 300);
    alert (contentLoaded);
});
var currentAnchor = null;

//Function which chek if there are anchor changes, if there are, sends the ajax petition
function checkAnchor(){
//Check if it has changes
if(currentAnchor != document.location.hash){
    currentAnchor = document.location.hash;
    //if there is not anchor, the loads the default section
    if(!currentAnchor){
        query = "page=1";
    }
    else
    {
        //Creates the  string callback. This converts the url URL/#main&id=2 in URL/?section=main&id=2
        var splits = currentAnchor.substring(1).split('&');
        //Get the section
        var page = splits[0];
        delete splits[0];
        var query = "page=" + page;

    }
    alert ("hello");
    //Send the petition
    $("#loading").show();

    alert (contentLoaded);

    if (!contentLoaded){
    $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
        $("#content").append(data);
        $("#loading").hide();
        });

        alert (contentLoaded);

    }
    contentLoaded = true;


}
}
```

here is my

**callbacks.php**

```
<?php  
//Captures the petition and load the suitable section  
switch($_GET['page']){  
case "4100errors" : 
  include 'template/4100errors.php';
  break;
case "4100downloads" :      
 include 'template/4100downloads.php';
  break;
}
?>
```

And my main file

**4100.php**

```
<?php
include 'template/header.php';
include 'template/4100menu.php';
include 'template/log.php';
include 'template/links.php';
include 'template/4100breadcrumbs.php';
?>
<div class="left-widget">
<div style="display:none; position:absolute; top:-9999; z-index:-100;">
<a href="4100.php?page=4100downloads"></a>
<a href="4100.php?page=4100errors"></a>
</div>

<div id="side-nav-bar" class="Mwidget">
    <h3>Contents</h3>
        <ul class="tree">
            <li><a href="#4100downloads" class="links" >Downloads</a>        </li>
            <li><a href="#4100errors" class="links">Error  Troubleshooting</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
   </div>

    <div id="content" style="margin-top:100px; margin-left:300px;">  
  <?
switch ($_GET['page']) 
{
case "4100downloads": include 'template/4100downloads.php'; break;
case "4100errors": include 'template/4100errors.php'; break;


}
?>

</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

**4100dowloads.php**

```
Downloads test page
```

**4100error.php**

```
Errors test page
```

Also you can look at the test page here http://period3designs.com/phptest/1/4100.php

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what the specific question is here?

Comment: Look at the update above. I sincerely hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"What is the proper way to use .get() in conjunction with .one() (or .live()) so that an external php file is appended only once?"*

`.one()` and `live()` really have little to do with `$.get`. They're only for event handling.

If you intend to run the code every `50ms` as you are, but want to *replace* the current content, then use `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

```
$("#content").html(data);
```

This will overwrite the old content.

---

I assume you're aware of this, but just to be sure, your code is running at an interval because of this...

```
$().ready(function(){
    setInterval("checkAnchor()", 50); // better--> setInterval(checkAnchor, 50);
});
```

If you only want it once on document load, then do this...

```
$(document).ready(checkAnchor);
```

Comment: I tried to run it once at document ready but it's acting exactly as I expected - it's running it once and then never checking for the anchor, which gets updated without reloading the page. I ended up commenting it out and going the .one() route. Thanks for pointing out the interval though. That was definitely on the way. And again to clarify, I want to append each page only once, not to replace one with another

Answer (score 2):

Just use a boolean flag to determine if you loaded the data yet or not. Set it to false on page load, and just after the call to `$.get` set it to true. Then, wrap your `$.get` with an `if (!contentLoaded) { $.get ... }`.

That way you will execute the `$.get` only once.

BTW: `$.one` is used to bind an event to an element, that will execute only once and then unbind it self from it.

Comment: darn it they are kicking me out of the office because it's too late but this makes a lot of sense! I have faith in an hour or so when I get to my home computer I'll be able to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RenoDimitrova: no problem, let me know how it went when you try it out. Good luck!

Comment: ok so sorry for the delay but my brain is refusing to work for me anymore. Anyway, check up the updated code. I tried what you said but I think the problem is with the constant running of the `checkAnchor()`.Or I'm not seeing what's obviously wrong here. I'm starting to look at other options...

Comment: your `contentLoaded` flag starts at false, goes to true after the first `checkAnchor()`, and then stays true for the rest of the execution - which means it will execute the `$.get` every time. you need to change the `if` to `if (!contentLoaded) { $.get(..); }`. That way it will run once and then never again. If this is what you wanted out of it...

Comment: I did exactly that (I've updated the code above and my live test page to reflect the change) but what I'm seeing from the alerts I have on the test page is that it changes from false to true the first time it's loaded. Then if I click on `downloads` link in the sidbar the flag is already set to true so the $.get() function is never ran and none of the pages ever appear. (Unless I'm reloading the page with the url including the hash - 4100.php#downloads)

Comment: why are you using `.one()` if you want to event to happen when you click on it again? `.one()` means that the first time you click on the anchor it will execute your code, and then it won't happen ever again. What code exactly do you need to happen once? the `$.get` or everything inside the `click` event handler?

Comment: I'm sorry I've been away from this thread but I was trying to figure out if the problem is the unnecessary complex ui design. However, I did figure out the proper way to use .one() in my case. I'm going to choose @amnotiam's response as the answer mainly because it led me to the right path of getting rid of the interval function. However, if I could give you good feedback some other way for all your patience and helpfulness just let me know how - I'm still new here...

Comment: @RenoDimitrova: of course you should choose the answer that helped you the most! The most you can do is upvote mine if it helped you too. Anyways, I'm quite happy with your gratitude, and that's enough for me :)