# How to append data only one time after click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, append

So, i have this little function:

```
carousel_controls_buttons.live('click', function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
       info_board_span.append(info_board_description);
       e.preventDefault();
    }, 450);
});
```

What i'm trying to do is stop appending `info_board_description` more then one time after two, three fast clicks. When i do this this data appends more than one time and i have content duplication. How can i stop this for some time, f.e. this 450ms? Thx for help.

Comment: have a read of [Using .one() with .live() jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796207/using-one-with-live-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout` function:

```
var t = '';
carousel_controls_buttons.live('click', function(e){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function(){
          info_board_span.append(info_board_description);
          e.preventDefault();
    }, 450);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xhSvC/

Note that `live` method  is deprecated, you should use `on` method instead.

Comment: this works perfectly, thx man, i have soma ajax conetent loading after every click and this is the one and only right way :) thx

Answer (score 3):

Use a boolean to control it.

```
var flag = true;
carousel_controls_buttons.live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (flag) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           info_board_span.append(info_board_description);
           flag = true;
       }, 450);
       flag = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i have ajax content loading after every click, and i need to append this content one by one, but  one time, wait some time and append another, so this is no good way bc this is stopping all of my ajax actions after one appends

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers ought to work, I would like to introduce you to the concept of `debounce` & `throttle`.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ is one plugin you may use to achieve what you need, ie, ensure a function is executed only once per x seconds.

> Throttle versus debounce
>
> Both throttling and debouncing will rate-limit execution of a
>   function, but which is appropriate for a given situation?
>
> Well, to put it simply: while throttling limits the execution of a
>   function to no more than once every delay milliseconds, debouncing
>   guarantees that the function will only ever be executed a single time
>   (given a specified threshhold).

```
carousel_controls_buttons.live('click', function(e) {
    $.debounce(450, function() {
       info_board_span.append(info_board_description);
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an count over there say var count=0; increment when hit and check for the condition if count==1 append it if not leave it

Answer (score 0):

There is a one event for achieve this:

```
carousel_controls_buttons.one('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
       info_board_span.append(info_board_description);
       e.preventDefault();
    }, 450);
});
```